# How to Create the Custom Plugin in Tricentis QTest that customizes UI

Tags: qtest

How Can I Create a Custom Plugin in Tricentis QTest that Customizes Custom UI?

I need to add a Custom UI like a button on the existing QTest Test Case UI (Shown in the Below Image) and I want to call Rest API at the click of that button. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Is the Custom plugin the only way to achieve this or there is any other way to do this task?